# How do I stop Facebook from suggesting my friends join my closed Facebook groups?

Tags: facebook-groups, facebook-privacy

How to make my closed Facebook groups not show in "proposed"?
My friend can see closed groups where I am a member.

Answer (score -2):

Not possible. That option is there for marketing purposes.